# How to replace value in type with preserving keys?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have initial type and type of keys that should be handled:

```js
import { Prisma } from "@prisma/client";

// initial type
type X = {
  a: number;
  b?: null;
  c: null;
}

type Keys = 'b' | 'c'

// final type
type Y = {
  a: number;
  b?: typeof Prisma.DbNull;
  c: typeof Prisma.DbNull;
}

                // X         // Keys      
type Generic<InitialType, KeysToHandle> = ...
```

Is it possible to get type Y from type X using Generic?

Comment: This is very similar to the question you just deleted; should I spend any effort engaging here or is this one likely to be deleted also?

Comment: Assuming it stays, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NdEQYm) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is called a [Mappd Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).
Here is a type `Transform` that modifies property types based on provided keys.

```
import { Prisma } from "@prisma/client";

type InitialType = {
  a: number;
  b?: null;
  c: null;
}

type Keys = 'b' | 'c'

type Transform<T, K extends keyof T, U = typeof Prisma.DbNull> = {
  [Key in keyof T]: Key extends K ? U : T[Key]
}

type FinalType = Transform<InitialType, Keys>
```